# I Can't run .class file from CMD

Tags: java

I Have this error when i try to run my java class
`Error: Could not find or load main class Main.class Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main.class`

Comment: How are you running this? Is your class in a package?

Comment: Are you running it as `java Main.class`? In that case you need to run `java Main`, without the `.class` extension.